# Is there a way to generate a pdf file with editable text (comments or markups) using Prawn libaray in Ruby that can be modified later?

Tags: ruby, pdf, prawn

I have been using Prawnpdf in Ruby to generate pdf documents. The only issue that I have is that I cannot modify the rendered text in the pdf file afterwards (using Bluebeam or Adobe Acrobot Pro). Is there a specific method in the document that allows me to create text which later can be modified in a pdf software? (similar to when you use markup tools in for exmaple Bluebeam)

This is the method that I am currently using to generate a text in a pdf document:

```
        require "prawn"

        Prawn::Document.generate(
          filename,
          # margin: 1/4" which is going to be 18 pts.
          margin: 0,
          page_size: page_size_str,
          page_layout: :landscape,
        ) do

        start_new_page(size: page_size, layout: :landscape)

        text_box "Sample text that later can be edited in Bluebeam or Adobe Acrobot with a single click", at: [80, 100]

        end
```

If this is not possible with Prawn, is there any pdf writer library in Ruby that allows printing editable text?

Thank you,

Comment: Maybe my question was not clear enough. If by editable, you mean they are not image but text, that is right. But, the editable text that I am referring to is a markup (in Bluebeam) or comments (in Adobe Acrobot or Foxit reader). These markups can be easily modified with a free version of these software. If you add a markup text in Bluebeam you can easily modify that in Foxit or free version of Adobe Acrobot (will be identified as comments in these software). Can prawn perform the same thing in Ruby?

Comment: There’s a [`Prawn::Core::Annotations`](https://github.com/prawnpdf/pdf-core/blob/master/lib/pdf/core/annotations.rb) class.

Comment: BTW, there’s a huge difference between the free Acrobat Reader and Acrobat Pro. You might want to clarify what editing capabilities you are referring to. Maybe with an example.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in Prawn but you maybe have to build the necessary annotation objects yourself, depending on what kind of annotation you want.

As @Stefan pointed out, some annotations can be easily generated:

```
require 'prawn'

Prawn::Document.generate('file.pdf') do |pdf|
  pdf.text_annotation([100, 100, 200, 200], "Some text here")
end
```